# JavaScript Promise Reject

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm returning Promise inside my service;

```js
  @Action
  [Actions.LOGIN](credentials) {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      ApiService.post("auth/login", credentials)
        .then(({ data }) => {
          this.context.commit(Mutations.SET_AUTH, data);
          resolve();
        })
        .catch(({ response }) => {
          this.context.commit(Mutations.SET_ERROR, response.data.message);
          reject();
        });
    });
  }
```

And in my `sign.vue` file I'm trying to catch error;

```js
   store
  .dispatch(Actions.LOGIN, values)
  .then(() => {
    Swal.fire({
      text: "All is cool! Now you submit this form",
      icon: "success",
      buttonsStyling: false,
      confirmButtonText: "Ok, got it!",
      customClass: {
        confirmButton: "btn fw-bold btn-light-primary",
      },
    }).then(function () {
      // Go to page after successfully login
      router.push({ name: "dashboard" });
    });
  })
  .catch(() => {
    Swal.fire({
      text: store.getters.getErrors[0],
      icon: "error",
      buttonsStyling: false,
      confirmButtonText: "Try again!",
      customClass: {
        confirmButton: "btn fw-bold btn-light-danger",
      },
    });
  });
```

When returning error in service catch block is cathcing. But in vue file catch block not catching, it's going to then block. Why is that happening? is reject command wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You must return the promise, if the expectation is to have a *continuation* in the `catch` block:

```js
.then(() => {
  return Swal.fire({
  /* ... */
  });
})
```

Comment: It's still not catching cath block. Still if service return `reject`, **success** notification showing